# Private section swift 3 in Struct / Class definition

Tags: swift, swift3, access-specifier

In C++ you can specify "public: / private:" sections within your class definitions. Is there a way to do this in Swift 3 or do I have to use the keyword "private" on front of every object I wish to be private?

Comment: You have to do it on every object. I do not think there is other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have

```
class MyClass {

}
```

You can declare scoped extensions, e.g.

```
fileprivate extension MyClass  {
     var someThing: String { // This computed property is fileprivate
         return "ABC"
     }

     func doSomething() {    // This func is fileprivate
     }
}

public extension MyClass  {
     var someOtherThing: String { // This computed property is public
         return "123"
     }

     func doSomethingElse() {     // This func is public
     }
}
```

However, you can only declare stored properties in your class definition, so this *won't*  work…

```
private extension MyClass {
    let myName = "Fred"    
}
```

In this case you need to apply the scope keyword to the property itself…

```
class MyClass {
    private let myName = "Fred"
}
```

Comment: Just one note, private extensions can contain static private properties which can be used in the body of the extension.

Comment: This `fileprivate` keyword is available in swift 2.3? Or starts from swift 3.0.

Comment: `fileprivate` is available since Swift 3.0